# Why ant design Drawer not showing close icon?

Tags: reactjs, antd

This piece of code not showing any close icon in the **ant design Drawer**.

```
<Drawer
        title="Job ID: 9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d"
        placement="right"
        closable={false}
        onClose={onJobDetailsDrawerClose}
        visible={jobDetailsDrawervisible}
        width="75%"
        closeIcon={<CloseOutlined />}
      >
```

But the drawer **API** showed this:

[image: API reference from ant design]

Any idea why the Drawer not showing up any close icon?

Comment: Can you provide us any fiddle link or sandbox>

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-dew-wrx96 Working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears the close icon is hidden when you specify

```
closable={false}
```

[Drawer API - closable](https://ant.design/components/drawer/#API)

> Whether a close (x) button is visible on top right of the Drawer
> dialog or not.

[image]

With this prop set to false the drawer is toggleable externally.